# Can I claim standard business expenses incurred earlier than the date my LLC was formed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, limited-liability-company, expenses

I want to form an LLC for my web development business. However, I incurred a bunch of expenses during the year that I'd like to be able to deduct.

I know you can claim startup costs, but these are not startup costs per se, but rather things like travel expenses, membership fees, software, etc.

Can that stuff be claimed if it was incurred in the same year, but prior to formulation of the LLC?

Comment: What is the reason you don't consider those to be start up costs?

Comment: The good news is, you **can in fact** claim these in the "startup costs" category.

Comment: I guess I would normally classify them as normal operating costs - supplies, travel, etc - just in the "other income" category of my personal income tax return. But if, in starting an LLC, I am allowed to classify them as startup expenses, that's great I guess.